# C# Calling Methods in Generic Classes

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

I am extending the ImageBox control from EmguCV. The control's `Image` property can be set to  anything implementing the `IImage` interface.

All of the following implement this interface:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte>
Image<Ycc, Byte>
Image<Hsv, Byte>
```

Now I want to call the `Draw` method on the object of the above type (what ever it may be).

The problem is when I access the Image property, the return type is `IImage`. IImage does not implement the `Draw` method, but all of the above do.

I believe I can cast the object of type `IImage` to one of the above (the right one) and I can access the `Draw` method. But how do I know what the right one is? If you have a better way of doing this, please suggest that as well.

**EDIT**

Sorry, but I forgot to mention an important piece of information. The Draw method for each of the above class takes one different argument. For e.g. `Draw` for `Image<Bgr, Byte>` takes  an argument of type `Bgr` and the `Draw` for `Image<Hsv, Byte>` takes an argument of type `Hsv` instead.

Comment: Do have access to the IImage and Image code?

Comment: EmguCV is an open source project, though I really prefer to just use their binaries :)

Comment: It doesn't look that image interface/implementation is well designed.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered. I learned some very good things. The accepted answer may in general lead to very sloppy code. But in my case, I just have to do it once and I don't want to edit the EmguCV source files. I used this, so I have marked that as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
void foo( IImage image )
{
    if ( image is Image<Bgr, Byte> )
    {
        ((Image<Bgr, Byte>)(image)).Draw();
    }

    // handle the other types the same way.
}
```

Comment: I think it is better to have one implementation instead of many ifs.

Comment: This is just begging for sloppy code.  Now for every type you are going to have to add the code in multiple places.  It would probably be better to extrapolate this logic, and all the logic for the different image types, into some sort of renderer than do something like this.

Comment: I agree there are other good answers and this in general may lead to very sloppy code. But in my case, I just have to do it once and I don't want to edit the EmguCV source files. I used this, so I will mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Add an IDrawableImage that inherits from IImage.

```
public interface IDrawableImage : IImage
{
   void Draw(object val);
   void Draw();
}
```

Then you can simply do the following:

```
var drawableImage = container.Image as IDrawableImage;
if (drawableImage != null)
    drawableImage.Draw();
```

To match your clarification above:

```
public interface IDrawableImage<T, B> : IDrawableImage where B : byte
{
    void Draw<T>(T val);
}
```

then if you know the type:

```
var value = new Hvr();
var drawableImage = container.Image as IDrawableImage<Hvr, Byte>;
if (drawableImage != null)
    drawableImage.Draw(value);
```

if you don't

```
var value = new Hvr();
var drawableImage = container.Image as IDrawableImage;
if (drawableImage != null)
    drawableImage.Draw(value);
```

Comment: It's a best practice to create interfaces for these kind of problems. Checking each implementation (as in Adel's example) violates the Open/closed principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) and creates high coupling (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_science%29). With this interface, you can create a new `Image<T, Byte>` type and use that without altering any code that calls the `Draw` method.

Comment: Thats exactly why I suggested this method, doing the large if statements has bit me in the rear more than I can count over the years, especially when you start doing this everywhere. All of the sudden you need an internal wiki article on how to add a new type to it because it touches so much code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly - Image class implements draw method. I don't know how you are going to use it, but you can do in this way:

```
private void DrawImage<T1, T2>(Image<T1, T2> image)
{
    image.Draw();
}
```

The main problem about above is that the caller of the above method should specify the T1 and T2 types.

If you don't have control about IImage interface and its implementations then I think you will be choosing from two solutions: specify T1 and T2 types or having ifs/switches with all possible IImage implementations.

If you have access to the IImage interface and Image class then you should add generic IImage interface and add Draw method to it.

Comment: this way you need different methods for different generic types.

Comment: Why? You just call the above method with necessary type parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You'll should have a shared interface that adds Draw().

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that the Image<T,U> that you'll have (regardless of the types) will have the Draw method, you can use reflection and hack around it:

I would do it as an extension method:

```
public static void Draw(this IImage image)
{
   var method = image.GetType().GetMethod("Draw");
   if(method != null)
   {
      method.Invoke(image,null);
   }
}
```

A bit of a hack, but then again, I would say that the API isn't properly designed. There should at least be some Drawer class or something that would know how to act on an image.

Comment: No, reflections are slow and proposed soltions is not a natural way of how reflections should be used.

Comment: If you create a delegate from the MethodInfo and cache that instead of looking it up each time, calling it repeatedly won't be slow at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing a critical piece of information: the code you would like to write.

We need to know how you intend to write the code which calls the `Draw(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use dynamic methods and take your chances.